# Script for "x is what percentage of y"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to calculate "x is what percentage of y" using Python. For example: "2 is what of 149?" Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: You mean 2 / 149 * 100%?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a tutorial service, and it's definitely not a math tutoring service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not so hard to calculate percentage.

Divide 2 by 149 and multiply by 100%:

```
def percent(part, whole):
    return 100 * float(part)/float(whole)
```

Call it:

```
result = percent(2, 149)
print result #Should print 1.3...
```